# Unable to write index into CSV file

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to write the index values in a csv file but I am getting error.

code used for writing into csv

```
test = df.sort_values(['sqdist'], ascending=[False])
for i in range(len(test)):
 print(test.index[i])
```

The above code gives me output like this. These are the index values and I am trying to write this in a CSV using the below code.

```
7163
4332
3319
1213
1212
6984
4331
4362
6393
515

Trying to write the above output into a csv file exactly like how i see above.


    
with open ("scores.txt",'w') as f1:
        writer = csv.writer(f1, lineterminator='\n', )
        for i in range(len(test)):
            writer.writerow(test.index[i])
    
    print("Saved the scores in the text file score.txt")


Error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-748f3db1997a> in <module>()
     94         writer = csv.writer(f1, lineterminator='\n', )
     95         for i in range(len(test)):
---> 96             writer.writerow(test.index[i])
     97 print("Saved the scores in the text file ranking.txt")
     98 

Error: iterable expected, not numpy.int64
```

Comment: What error do you get? Could you post the full traceback?

Comment: have you tried `for i in range(len(test))` instead of just `range(test)`

Comment: Is test variable a list object containing integer values (e.g. test = [4,3,2,6]) ? If so then `for i in range(test):` would cause an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open ("/scores.txt",'w') as f1:
        writer = csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n', )
        for i in test:
            writer.writerow([i])
    
 print("Saved the scores in the text file scores.txt")
```

Above is the modified code

Comment: this is only storing the first value

Comment: writer.writerow([i]) - this statement will write the contents into the csv file. Ex: test =['Rahul','Virat','Sunil'] and modify the statement to writer.writerow([i,test[i]]) you will be able to write multiple values in to the CSV file

Comment: please check my updated code and error

Comment: With the code you mentioned i will be able to write only the index values of my output but I want to write the exact output values I got.

Comment: can you try the modified code

Comment: I tried and nothing saves into csv file. Also, I think the index values I get in test.index[i] are not list.

Comment: writer.writerow([i]) - this statement will help you to convert the individual value as a list and write it into the csv file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241586/discussion-between-ksp-and-prasanna-p).

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `writerow()` must be a sequence, since each element of the sequence will be a separate field in the CSV.

If you're just writing a single field, wrap it in a list or tuple.

```
writer.writerow([i])
```

Although if you just have one field, there's not much point in using the `csv` module in the first place.

Comment: i want each value to go into a new line/new row

Comment: So what's so hard about that? `f1.write(str(row) + '\n')`?